# How to call scala's Option constructors from Java

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scala-option

I am working on a mixed java/scala project, and I am trying to call a scala object's method from Java.  This method takes an `Option[Double]` as a parameter.  I thought this would work:

```
Double doubleValue = new Double(1.0);
scalaObj.scalaMethod(new Some(doubleValue));
```

But Eclipse tells me "The constructor Some(Double) is undefined".

Should I be calling the constructor for `scala.Some` differently?

Comment: In Java, type parameters for _methods_ can be inferred (sometimes), but type parameters for _constructors_ never.

Comment: @Alexey good to know, I think that is probably the source of my troubles.  I am still having problems, even if I parameterize `Some<Double>`, though (see my comment on the answer from @user654801).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In Scala you normally lift to Option as follows:

```
scala> val doubleValue = Option(1.0)
doubleValue: Option[Double] = Some(1.0)
```

`()` is a syntactic sugar for `apply[A](A obj)` method of `Option`'s companion object. Therefore, it can be directly called in Java:

```
Option<Double> doubleValue = Option.apply(1.0);
```

Comment: This helped me as well.

Scala

    `def startServer(localBind: Option[Int] = None): Unit = { ... }`

Java call

    `Option<Integer> so = Option.apply(9002);`
    `AcmeClient.startServer(so);`

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a Some instance that way, this compiles for me,

```
Some<Double> d = new Some<Double>(Double.valueOf(1));
```

The problem may be the missing generics, try doing,

```
scalaObj.scalaMethod(new Some<Double>(doubleValue));
```

Comment: Hmm, when I try that I get "The type Some is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Double>".  Could this just be a deficiency in the Eclipse/Scala integration?  I do have `import scala.Some;` so I believe I am using the right `Some`.

Comment: This approach has the downside of lifting `null` reference to `Some(null)`, instead of `None`. You'd better use `Option` companion object for correct lifting.

Comment: @Vasil, thanks, that makes sense.  Your (other) answer solved my problem.