# Creating Some(object) from Java

Tags: scala, interop

I need to call from Java a Scala API that has a parameter with signature `Option[Activity]`.

I want to pass `Some(this)`, whose class is a derived class from `Activity`.

I have tried many things:

- `new Some<Activity>.apply(this)`
- `Some.apply((Activity)this)`
- `Option.apply((Activity)this)`

but I get a compilation error like this:

```
actual argument Some<Activity> cannot be converted 
to Option<Class<? extends Activity>> by method invocation conversion
```

What is the right way of passing this?

Related questions:

- It talks about `Option[Double]`, and doesn't have inheritance issues: [How to call scala's Option constructors from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287451/how-to-call-scalas-option-constructors-from-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you quite sure your method takes an `Option[Activity]`? Because that message suggests it's taking an `Option[Class[_ <: Activity]]`. Please post the Scala code and how you're calling it.

Comment: A stupid error!.  The exact Scala signature was: `Option[Class[_ <: Activity]]`.  That explains everything.